# How to get all list catgories of joomla15?

Tags: joomla1.5

I don't know how to get list categories of joomla, I need module to do that...So, Can you help me ?

Comment: your question is not clear at all. Can you re-phrase it or may be show code code you tried..!

Comment: your question should be more specific to understand..

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I'm afraid we will not be able to help you since your question is too short and lacks detail. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this : http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/sections-a-categories/2780

However your question is unclear.

Comment: Sorry .Because I come from VIET NAM. so, my english is bad